# babel does not inject relative requires into the output

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, requirejs, babeljs

I run babel against my source files, i want to output one single file, with all the relative imports injected inside the file.

## Source structure

```
src
│   index.js
│   relative-file.js    
│
└───some-folder
        another-relative-file.js
```

the index file requires `relative-file`, and the `relative-file` requires `another-relative-file`.

## Expected output

`index.js` with no relative requires, everything is injected inside this one file.

## Actual output

`index.js` with `require('./relative-file')` inside.

## Tried babel-cli commands

```
babel src --out-file distribution/index.js
```

output a dir will put output multiple files requiring each other just like the source.

```
babel src --out-dir distribution
```

Comment: What does this have to do with reactjs?

Comment: @PerSvensson i was writing the code for a react library so i put it here without thinking much about it. removed

Comment: Babel does not do this, you could however use Babel via Browserify or Webpack to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think babel helps with eliminating requires. You need to use a bundler like webpack in combination with babel to achieve what you want.